# How to view a dropdown menu with Jquery show() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code . I want to view and hide menu with slow or fade in and out or slideup and slidedown.
Please help me!

```
$(function(){

    $("ul.dropdown li").hover(function(){

        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible').slideDown("slow");

    }, function(){

        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');

    });

    $("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &raquo; ");

});
```

Comment: I want to add show(2000) or slideUp(.......) or fade(...) with this code

Comment: It will help if you post your markup as well.